# Add Controller not working on ASP.NET MVC 5 on VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm currently working on ASP.NET MVC 5 project on VS 2013 Ultimate. However, Add Controller... option when I right-click on the Controllers and Add View on Views folders are non-existent. I've checked the MvcScaffolding installed and even upgraded VS 2013 to Update 5 and tried to uninstalling the DevExpress ASP.NET components. But, nothing seem to work. What is the best remedy to resolve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Your project has a reference to the MVC assembly (preferably through NuGet)? Also, what are the values in the `ProjectTypeGuids` section of the .csproj file?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft.ASP.NET MVC (5.2.3) already installed

Comment: Might need to try [reinstalling](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages) the MVC package: `Update-Package -reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`. If that doesn't help, (again) verify the project type GUID.